# How to create GlobalVariable during runtime in katalon using scriptmode?

Tags: selenium, groovy, ui-automation, katalon-studio

I m new to katalon studio tool and trying to add GlobalVariable during runtime by taking "variable Name" & "Value" as inputs.
I m come across block of code which will help me in this. But i m facing difficulties in understanding this piece of code,because it uses metaprogramming in Groovy.

```
void addGlobalVariable(String name, def value) {
    MetaClass mc = script.evaluate("internal.GlobalVariable").metaClass
    String getterName = "get" + name.capitalize()
    mc.static."$getterName" = { -> return value }
    //mc.static."$name" = value
}
```

i am getting "InvocationTargetException" when i m running it.and also katalon IDE doesn't recognize these keywords "script","evaluate" & static.

you looking for clarity on this block code or you can suggest me any other possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

After my test, the following code can achieve the effect:
1.Define a Keyword:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
package com.becelever.util
public class GlobalVariableUtils {

    @Keyword
    static void addGlobalVariable(String name, def value) {
        GroovyShell shell1 = new GroovyShell()
        MetaClass mc = shell1.evaluate("internal.GlobalVariable").metaClass
        String getterName = "get" + name.capitalize()
        mc.'static'."$getterName" = { -> return value }
        mc.'static'."$name" = value
    }
}
```

2.then invoke it and verify:

```
CustomKeywords.'com.becelever.util.GlobalVariableUtils.addGlobalVariable'('localURL', 'katalon.com')

println(GlobalVariable.localURL)
println(GlobalVariable.getLocalURL())
```

Note: I found that the first letter of the variable could not be capitalized. For example, if I changed it to "LocalURL", it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-import the required libraries. You do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.